# New data replaces old data in ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an app in which i need to show data in List view.For that i am using custom Adapter.To store my info i have created Model class with getter and setter.The info which i am getting is in Json Format.So i am parsing it and storing it in my Model Class.I have user ArrayList to store info.But my prob is when parsing data from Json array the new data replaces the old data in the ArrayList.
For example

```
loop 1
data=1,2,5
ArrayList at [0]=1,2,5

loop 2
data=2,2,2
ArrayList at [0]=2,2,2
             [1]=2,2,2
```

Now why this is happening??

Model Class

public class SearchModel {

```
public class SearchModel {

    private String category, minExp, maxExp, postedOn, counts, applied, position, desc, type, hour, status, expiryDate, address, gender, religion, summary, requestId, requestorId;

    public SearchModel(String category, String minExp, String maxExp, String postedOn, String counts, String applied, String position, String desc, String type, String hour, String status, String expiryDate, String address, String gender, String religion, String summary, String requestId, String requestorId) {
        this.category = category;
        this.minExp = minExp;
        this.maxExp = maxExp;
        this.postedOn = postedOn;
        this.counts = counts;
        this.applied = applied;
        this.position = position;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.type = type;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.status = status;
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
        this.address = address;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.religion = religion;
        this.summary=summary;
        this.requestId = requestId;
        this.requestorId = requestorId;
    }
}
```

Async Class

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        values = new ArrayList<SearchModel> ();
        data = new SearchModel ();

        super.onPostExecute (s);
        if (!s.trim ().contains ("Table")) {
            Crouton.makeText ((android.app.Activity) c, "Nothing found", Style.INFO).show ();
        } else {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (s);
                JSONObject NewDataSet = jsonObject.getJSONObject ("NewDataSet");
                if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject table = NewDataSet.getJSONObject ("Table");
                    data.setAddress (table.getString ("Address"));
                    data.setCounts (table.getString ("Candidate_Counts"));
                    values.add (data);

                } else if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray tableArray = NewDataSet.getJSONArray ("Table");
                    for (int i = 0; i < tableArray.length (); i++) {
                        JSONObject table = tableArray.getJSONObject (i);
                        data.setAddress (table.getString ("Address"));
                        data.setCounts (table.getString ("Candidate_Counts"));
                        values.add (data);

                    }

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is that you're not creating a new instance of `SearchModel` each time through the `for` loop, so `values.add (data);` is just adding another reference to the same `SearchModel` instance. That is, every item in your ArrayList is pointing to one object. Try changing your code as follows:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    values = new ArrayList<SearchModel> ();
    // data = new SearchModel ();   << Remove this

    // super.onPostExecute (s);  << You don't need this, by the way.
    if (!s.trim ().contains ("Table")) {
    ...
    ...
        if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject table = NewDataSet.getJSONObject ("Table");

            data = new SearchModel ();  //  << Add this
            data.setAddress (table.getString ("Address"));
            data.setCounts (table.getString ("Candidate_Counts"));
            values.add (data);
        } else if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray tableArray = NewDataSet.getJSONArray ("Table");
            for (int i = 0; i < tableArray.length (); i++) {
                JSONObject table = tableArray.getJSONObject (i);

                data = new SearchModel ();  //  << Add this
                data.setAddress (table.getString ("Address"));
                data.setCounts (table.getString ("Candidate_Counts"));
                values.add (data);
            }
        }
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Sir please can you help me how to create the model??
Ans i m nt nly having address and counts bt many fields ,so how can i construct a model

Comment: Well, if you have a _lot_ of data fields, then the way you're doing it now is probably the way to go. Just don't create the instances until you need them. That is, don't call `data = new SearchModel ();` until right before you call `setAddress()`, `setCounts()`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, in that case, forget about the constructor. Your way is fine. Just move `data = new SearchModel ();` to the _beginning_ of the for loop, and add it also to the `JSONObject` section of the if block. Gimme a minute and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I just wanted to be in touch so that i can learn from you.If u want i can post my email id and there u can reply me?